# Is it possible to install a complex server inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker

It appears that Docker is better suited for single process applications and services, but is it capable to offer a stable containment for a more complex application ( that has multiple processes, listening ports, considerable storage usage ) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332662/start-full-container-in-docker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! You can use Supervisor, monit, runit, or even a "real" init system (including upstart or systemd) to run multiple processes. You can even use a cheap shell script like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
( while true; do run-process-1; done; ) &
( while true; do run-process-2; done; ) &
wait
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that I have a supervisor image and some examples on [github](https://github.com/Krijger/docker-cookbooks). In case someone thinks it usefull: I also wrote a [blog](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/) on this.

I mainly use supervisor to keep deamon processes running, but you could create complex environments as well (e.g. specify the order to start processes etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Sure checkout http://supervisord.org/ i am creating complete LAMP stacks for Magento development.