# stop a database container in docker automatically

Tags: docker

I'm setup a database container with a script rc.db which provide standard init commands like:

```
/etc/rc.db start
/etc/rc.db stop
/etc/rc.db status
```

In [Is it possible to install a complex server inside a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568048/is-it-possible-to-install-a-complex-server-inside-a-docker-container/20573717#20573717), I know I could use a simple script to start the db container(for example name as /etc/db_run.sh:

```
#/bin/sh
/etc/rc.db start
wait
```

And the Dockerfile
    ...
    RUN /etc/db_run.sh

Because close database correctly is important. I wish when the container be stopped, it could call the /etc/rc.db stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Docker tries to stop a container, it sends a SIGTERM signal, followed by a SIGKILL after a grace period. Just catch this signal and either call your script or pass it onto the DB process, whichever is appropriate.

I suspect that if you make the DB the main process running in the foreground, it will handle the signals correctly itself.

Comment: here contains a sample execution script http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint