# Docker Use LXC with Direct Host Networking

Tags: networking, docker, lxc

With the [release of Docker 0.11](http://blog.docker.io/2014/05/docker-0-11-release-candidate-for-1-0/), one can use the host's network directly by specifying `--net=host` when running the container. This allows me to bind to the host's IP address, which enables the use of [service discovery with consul](http://www.consul.io/) etc. However, if I have docker set to use LXC as the container engine, I do not see any of the interfaces except the loopback address. I would dearly love to keep using LXC as it enables me to easily [connect to a running container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932357/docker-enter-running-container-with-new-tty/20932974#20932974) and poke around for debugging.

Does anybody know how to configure docker + LXC so I can have direct host networking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug, please report it to the github repo. In the meantime, you can use pipework to do the same thing: github.com/jpetazzo/pipework.