# Pycharm doesn't recognize file or folder with remote interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, remote-debugging

In a file whose only content is

```
def test_sanity():
    pass
```

I am trying to run the file, named `test_something.py`.

The folder structure is

```
uv_metadata
|---uv_metadata
|------tests
|----------test_something.py
```

Getting the error

```
ssh://noam.s@ML:2202/home/noam.s/src/uv_metadata/venv/bin/python -u /home/noam.s/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py --target test_something.py::test_sanity
Testing started at 14:34 ...
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to C:/Users/noam.s/src/uv_metadata/uv_metadata/tests
Launching pytest with arguments test_something.py::test_sanity --no-header --no-summary -q in /home/noam.s

============================= test session starts ==============================
collected 0 items                                                              

============================ no tests ran in 0.00s =============================
ERROR: file or directory not found: test_something.py::test_sanity


Process finished with exit code 4

Empty suite
```

I notice the line `sh: 1: cd: can't cd to C:/Users/noam.s/src/uv_metadata/uv_metadata/tests`, which doesn't make sense. Here is how my remote interpreter is configured:

[image]

This just stopped working, I don't know what has changed.

**How to make Pycharm recognize the test folder again?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyCharm 2021.2.3 has a buggy deployment configuration, which can cause clashes and sometimes not work properly when some mappings are configured separately on the same interpreter, even from different projects.

Likely, I was using the same interpreter with a different mapping, from some other Pycharm instance.

I had to go to `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Deployment` and remove everything from the list.

Following is the state after everything was clean and I added a new interpreter.

[image]

I also cleaned the interpreter list

[image]

and it went back to work.

---

### A very inconvenient method to avoid this, but be safe

My method of working to avoid this is having only a single path mapping per interpreter.

If I need the same interpreter with different mappings, I create a new docker container, to make Pycharm think it is actually a different interpreter.

If I need the same mapping with a different interpreter, there isn't a problem.

For accessing the interpreter that runs inside a remote docker, I am tunneling PORT to 22 on the docker, and making ssh server run on the docker on startup, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70059793/913098), and mapping `~` to `~` in the docker, so the actual same venv is reflected in all dockers.