# Does docker internally uses system calls like chroot, unshare, nsenter, etc or a wrapper around lxc

Tags: docker, go, lxc, chroot, nsenter

I was going through an [article](https://ericchiang.github.io/post/containers-from-scratch/) to build containers from scratch without using docker just by making use of linux system calls like chroot, unshare, nsenter, etc.

Does docker internally a wrapper around these system calls, it seems like docker exec is not using nsenter as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873312/docker-exec-versus-nsenter-any-gotchas)

If docker is using these calls which golang binary is it using to have these system calls.

Or docker is a wrapper around lxc but it don't seems to me as per this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254956/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-lxd-and-lxc)

Can anyone point me out the exact low level stuff (system calls/lxc,etc) that docker is currently using to build a container.

Comment: Docker calls containerd which uses runc by default to create containers, so have a look at the runc project: https://github.com/opencontainers/runc

Answer (score 3):

Docker is not a wrapper around LXC.  Back in the old days it did use an LXC-based mechanism for starting containers, but that was [replaced by a native implementation](https://blog.docker.com/2014/03/docker-0-9-introducing-execution-drivers-and-libcontainer/).

As Docker is an open source project, you can see *exactly* what it's doing by browsing through [the source](https://github.com/moby/moby) (which has since [been renamed "moby"](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/04/21/docker_renames_open_source_code_moby/)).

The actual creation of containers is handled by the [libcontainer](https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/master/vendor/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer) component.