# How to run many commands in docker run and stay interactive?

Tags: docker

I run that:

```
docker run -it --restart always  --net=host myImage /bin/bash
```

And I stay interactive
then I run (inside the docker container)

```
/start.sh
```

and everything is ok

My idea is to run /start.sh directly with docker run command

I tried that:

```
docker run -it --restart always  --net=host myImage /bin/bash -c "/start.sh"
```

**Which seems to work, but once the start.sh finishes tasks, docker quits the interactive mode**

start.sh only contains starting service

```
service apache start;
service mysql start;
pm2 start /chat.js;
```

Comment: This is very common problem that everyone bumps into when starting with docker. The way you are trying to do it makes your script run as `PID 1` and after it stops, the container stops too. This happens because containers are up & running as long as PID 1 is running.

Comment: In the Dockerfile [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) there is a section that describes how you can run a starter script and then pass the Unix signals to a different executable by using `exec "$@"`. The idea here is that, this executable will be responsible to catch the signals and gracefully stop all the services that you are running.

Comment: You can also take a look at this: [Docker container will automatically stop after “docker run -d”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d) where `tail -f /dev/null` is proposed to keep the container running.

Comment: Understand the issue, but cannot really understand why there is no simple solution for such basic and common task

Comment: Would it work with tail -f /dev/null &
My goal is to have access to the console

Comment: Why don't you give it a try, put it as the last command of your `start.sh` file to see what happens. To access your container console use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932357/how-to-enter-in-a-docker-container-already-running-with-a-new-tty).